# when the model is too big in forge,it will flickering,how to solve it?

Tags: viewer, autodesk-forge, forge

I use forge in my project.But my model is so big that force can't work well.

When I move my model in a forge, it can not finish rendering right away.It will be flickering.This affects the normal work.

Such as this video：
[problem video](https://youtu.be/AOT3_-EaPOM)

1）I have tried  Model Consolidation, but this has no obvious effect.
[https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-consolidated-geometry][2]

This is the code：

```
var initializerOptions = {
   env: 'AutodeskProduction',
   useConsolidation: true,
   consolidationMemoryLimit: 150 * 1024 * 1024 // 150MB - Optional, defaults to 100MB
}

Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer( initializerOptions, function() {
  // ...
});
```

2）I want to merge elements and reduce the number of patches in the model.

I think my model is too big, it has too many elements and patches. So it wants to reduce them.But I don't find any good idea to solve it.

I have tried 3d Max, Maya, and Navisworks to merge elements and reduce the number of patches.But none of them worked well.I haven't found a better way to reduce patches and merge elements.

Do you have a good way to solve the flickering problem?

Answer (score 0):

The flickering issue you mentioned is not an issue but a side effect of the Progressive Rendering that the viewer is using. You cannot avoid it, this is how works Progressive Rendering. Consolidation will help on loading large scene, but not on the effect you're seeing. I am afraid there is no good answer on this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have tried viewer.setProgressiveRendering(false).This can help to solve flickering,but it affects performance very much.So I want to reduce the number of patches and merge elements,But I don't find any good idea to do this.I need a good way to do it.Do you have any good ideas?

Comment: Reducing the number of mesh on the original file format will not help either. WEBGL 1.0 requires a limited number of vertices (16-bit right now), so Forge is going to split them accordingly to that limit.